# Restrict user to update email at the time of reset password in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6 for resetting password, but issue is at the time of reset password user isalso given a field to update email, but i don't want to give user option to update email, user can only reset his password.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the authentication shipped with Laravel?

Comment: yes i am using Laravel default authentication

Comment: This field isn't usually there to update the email address of the user. It's there to provide an extra bit of security. If anyone figures out a reset link they would have to provide the email address too, which they shouldn't know, to reset a password.

Comment: so if any one enter wrong email address then the password will not be updated,

Comment: See the [ResetsPassword.php](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/auth-backend/ResetsPasswords.php#L47) trait and the [`reset` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php#L79) of the respective broker.

Comment: Exactly. You will have to provide the email address of the user attached to the reset token to change the password of said user.